# PHP. How to insert variable into $function(varible) in preg_replace_callback():

Tags: php, preg-replace, php-7, preg-replace-callback

Can someone help to fix next function. Its purpose is to find a text link and make it clickable with certain rules.
the problem is next:
I do not know how to insert variable into $function( *variable* ). The *variable* is generated in *preg_replace_callback*

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in....
```

```
function make_clickable($text)
{
    switch( 'strrev' )
    {
        case 'strrev':
            $function = 'strrev';
        break;
        
        case 'base64':
            $function = 'base64_encode';
        break;
        
        default:
            $function = '';
        break;
    }

    $text = preg_replace_callback("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#si", 
        function ($m){
            global $function;
        return "'$m[1]<a href=\"out.' . $phpEx . '?url=" . urlencode( $function( $m[2]) ). "\" target=\"_blank\">$m[2]</a>'";
    }, $text);


    return($text);
}

echo make_clickable('text http://example.net text');
// <a href="./out.php?url=net.example%2F%2F%3Aptth" target="_blank">http://example.net</a>
```

Comment: Please include the full error message you received

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to declare a global inside the `preg_replace_callback`. You can simply use the `use` statement, which can be used to make variables from the immediate scope available to a closure/anonymous function ([see manual, ex. 3 ff.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)); as follows:

```
$text = preg_replace_callback("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#si", 
    function ($m) use ($function) {
    return "'$m[1]<a href=\"out.' . $phpEx . '?url=" . urlencode( $function( $m[2]) ). "\" target=\"_blank\">$m[2]</a>'";
}, $text);
```

If you did `var_dump($function);` in your current code, you'd find out that the value of `$function` is `NULL`, therefore the error. Whenever your `switch` goes live, remember that the `default` case will result in an error. If you want to bypass the `$function`, you will need to have a condition to check for `if (!empty($function)) ...`, and return a transformed/plain URL accordingly.

In your code above, the variable `$phpEx` is also undefined. (I take it this is a work in progress function.) You can include it in the `use` statement, along with other variables you may want to use: `use ($function, $phpEx)` -- but you'll have to define it somewhere in your code, obviously. It's presumably going to be `.php`. You might want to define it as a constant instead, to make it available all across your code, without variable scope worries.

Comment: Glad to hear. :)